# Forcing client refresh after redeploying a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webserver

Scenario: There is a website with 700-900 concurrent unique visitors at any given time. There are pages on this site that auto-refresh, updating the displayed information. These pages are implemented so that sessions never timeout, to allow users to leave these pages always open.

Problem: After deploying updates to the website, users are still seeing the old markup if they had the page open from before the update.

Question: Is there a way to force refresh? I was thinking may be detect version/revision number on each callback and redirect to some message page if different. But I hope there's an easier way.

Thanks

Comment: In the end I implemented assembly version check and page refresh based on change detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you answered your own question. I don't think there's a good way to do this beyond detecting version or timestamp since last application restart.